# JavaScript save actions in Eclipse 2021-03?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I'm used to this functionality from Java development.

Is there a way to autoformat JavaScript files on save?

Comment: Unfortunately and as far as I know, no. Save actions are currently a pure Java thing. But a contribution for that to Eclipse WTP JSDT or Eclipse Wild Web Developer are certainly welcome.

Comment: JSDT no longer provides a JavaScript Editor. It's a feature gap that could be encouraged to close in https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/issues/474.